# PHP Multi Dimensional Array Performance Improvement

Tags: performance, php, algorithm

I have written the code below and I got the result what I wanted as below. But I needed pass to make the three-dimensional array for the result. Can I avoid to make three dimensional result? And I hope using only array_key_exists() and array_push() and unset().

The final result:

```
 Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [name] => Strawberry
        [id] => 10
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [name] => Strawberry
        [id] => 60
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [id] => 13
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [name] => Apple
        [id] => 20
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [name] => Apple
        [id] => 50
    )

[5] => Array
    (
        [id] => 28
    )

[6] => Array
    (
        [name] => Mandarin
        [id] => 30
    ))
```

The mid result:

```
  Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [name] => Strawberry
                [id] => 10
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [name] => Strawberry
                [id] => 60
            )

    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 13
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [name] => Apple
                [id] => 20
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [name] => Apple
                [id] => 50
            )

    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [id] => 28
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [name] => Mandarin
                [id] => 30
            )

    ))
```

My code:

```
<?php

$array       = array(
    array(
        'name' => 'Strawberry',
        'id' => '10'
    ),
    array(
        'id' => '13'
    ),
    array(
        'name' => 'Apple',
        'id' => '20'
    ),
    array(
        'id' => '28'
    ),
    array(
        'name' => 'Mandarin',
        'id' => '30'
    ),
    array(
        'name' => 'Apple',
        'id' => '50'
    ),
    array(
        'name' => 'Strawberry',
        'id' => '60'
    )
);
$arraylength = count($array);
$result      = array();//仮の結果。結果として三次元配列になる。
$bararray    = array();// idだけの配列を抜き出す。


for ($j = 0; $j < $arraylength; $j++) {
    if (array_key_exists('id', $array[$j]) == true && array_key_exists('name', $array[$j]) != true) {
        $newarr       = array();
        $newarr['id'] = $array[$j]['id'];
        array_push($bararray, $newarr);
    }
}// idのみの配列を抜き出した。
$j = 0;
for ($i = 0; $i < $arraylength; $i++) {

    $newarr = array();
    for ($k = $i; $k < $arraylength; $k++) {
        if (array_key_exists('id', $array[$i]) == true && array_key_exists('name', $array[$i]) == true && array_key_exists('name', $array[$k]) == true && $array[$k]['name'] == $array[$i]['name']) {
            array_push($newarr, $array[$k]);
            if ($i != $k) {
                unset($array[$k]);
                $arraylength--;
            }
            ;
        }
    }

    if (!$newarr) {
        array_push($result, $bararray[$j]);
        $j++;
    } else {
        array_push($result, $newarr);
    }
}//仮の結果、三次元配列はここまで
print_r($result);
$realresult   = array();//求めたい結果
$resultlength = count($result);
for ($k = 0; $k < $resultlength; $k++) {
    $resultArraylength = count($result[$k]);
    if ($resultArraylength == 1) {
        if (is_array($result[$k]) == true && array_key_exists(0, $result[$k]) == false) {
            array_push($realresult, $result[$k]);
        } else {
            array_push($realresult, $result[$k]['0']);
        }

    } else {
        for ($m = 0; $m < $resultArraylength; $m++) {
            array_push($realresult, $result[$k][$m]);
        }
    }

}

?>
```

Comment: This code is completely incoherent. You gave no description of what it's supposed to do and [the output](https://3v4l.org/a8JfA) produces no discernible pattern. I believe your code is broken and therefore the question is off-topic for CR. The code does not produce the result you say it produces - not even close.

Comment: Can you please add more explanation about the purpose of this code? We're looking for some background information, context, summary. The text in your question is also hard to understand, I don't understand what you are asking. Can you please clarify?

Comment: @Iwrestledabearonce. Okay, sorry about my description was unclear. I wanted to do two dimensional array without making three-dimensinal array. My output was totally different than this https://3v4l.org/BS6Jc ?Anyway thanks for your comment.

Comment: @kimiTanaka saying you want a 2d array instead of a 3d array does not explain what the code does. if your output is different then your code is different as 3v4l executes the code in all major versions of php. make sure you copied the code correctly because that is what this code produces.

Comment: @janos Sorry for being vague. I would like to avoid making three-dimensional array to get the result of two-dimensional array. I was reading and thinking to find a way though, I was seeking to use a way only using if-else statement to get the result not generating three-dimensional array as temporary array. Anyway thanks a lot. I appreciate it.

Comment: @kimiTanaka your code produces an array, you have said that several times. you are still not explaining what it **does**. is it supposed to sort an array? group items in the array? produce a specific pattern?

Comment: @I wrestled a bear once. You mean grouping items in the array such as making associative array “strawberry” => array( id = 10, id =  ...) and so on. No, this time I need to sort an array  by keeping the array name order not necessarily grouping items or finding a specific pattern. Anyway, thanks a lot for the clarification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can iterate (and reduce with each pass) the input array and group the like-names in the result array.  I am assuming all of the `id` values are already in the correct order.  See inline comments for how it works.

Code: ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/3c002666496a779813d71407dcc72f96b385a9b4))

```
$array=[
    ['name'=>'Strawberry','id'=>'10'],
    ['id'=>'13'],
    ['name'=>'Apple','id'=>'20'],
    ['id'=>'28'],
    ['name'=>'Mandarin','id'=>'30'],
    ['name'=>'Apple','id'=>'50'],
    ['name'=>'Strawberry','id'=>'60']
];

while($first=current($array)){  // while $array is not empty, grab the first subarray
    if(isset($first['name'])){  // if the grabbed subarray has a 'name' key
        foreach($array as $i=>$sub){  // perform full scan of $array 
            if(isset($sub['name']) && $sub['name']===$first['name']){
                $result[]=$sub;  // store subarrays with matching name value
                unset($array[$i]);  // remove stored subarray from $array
            }
        }
    }else{
        $result[]=array_shift($array);  // no 'name' key, just store and remove from $array
    }
}
var_export($result);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'name' => 'Strawberry',
    'id' => '10',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'name' => 'Strawberry',
    'id' => '60',
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    'id' => '13',
  ),
  3 => 
  array (
    'name' => 'Apple',
    'id' => '20',
  ),
  4 => 
  array (
    'name' => 'Apple',
    'id' => '50',
  ),
  5 => 
  array (
    'id' => '28',
  ),
  6 => 
  array (
    'name' => 'Mandarin',
    'id' => '30',
  ),
)
```

Comment: Thank you! It's more concise than I did. I think I need to get used to the function of PHP. I really appreciate it.